# How can I use a for loop to get respective stats from nested data

Tags: python

I have this data in python:

```
{
    u'stats': [
        u'Jul 23, 2015',
        u'Jul 24, 2015',
        u'Jul 25, 2015',
        u'Jul 26, 2015'
    ],
    u'tickers_data': [
        {u'amount': [936, 804, 977, 954], u'name': u'adv'}
    ]
}
```

The output expected is: store all dates and corresponding amount value to database.

How do I do this?

Comment: how are dates and amount linked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the dates:

```
data["stats"]
```

To get the amounts:

```
data["tickers_data"][0]["amount"]
```

Once you have those two lists, you can use the [`zip` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to combine the two lists into pairs of elements you can iterate over:

```
data = {
    u'stats': [
        u'Jul 23, 2015',
        u'Jul 24, 2015',
        u'Jul 25, 2015',
        u'Jul 26, 2015'
    ],
    u'tickers_data': [
        {u'amount': [936, 804, 977, 954], u'name': u'adv'}
    ]
}                                                                    
days = data['stats']
ticker = data['tickers_data'][0]['amount']

for day, amount in zip(days, ticker):
    print(day, "->", amount)
```

Output:

```
$ python3 x.py
Jul 23, 2015 -> 936
Jul 24, 2015 -> 804
Jul 25, 2015 -> 977
Jul 26, 2015 -> 954
```

If this is not what you meant that you need to provide more detail in your question on what you're trying to do and what you expect the end result to look like. You should also try to code up an initial attempt at what you're trying to do, and post that code in the question as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot.It worked.I want to insert this data in MySQLdb.Can you help me with how should i do it.starting from create table to insert query.------Column name-Date Amount and responding data :Jul 23, 2015 -> 936
Jul 24, 2015 -> 804
Jul 25, 2015 -> 977
Jul 26, 2015 -> 954

Comment: Great! Don't forget to mark an [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). For your second question, I would recommend that to start off you should search other questions here on StackOverflow or googling for tutorials like [this one](http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlpython/). Try to write up a solution first, *then* ask on StackOverflow if you get stuck, or if an error is being thrown, etc. That will help you become a better programmer and allow you to teach yourself vs. asking SO to walk you through each step. Good luck and happy hacking :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like the following to display it:

```
data_dict = {
    u'stats': [
        u'Jul 23, 2015',
        u'Jul 24, 2015',
        u'Jul 25, 2015',
        u'Jul 26, 2015'
    ],
    u'tickers_data': [
        {u'amount': [936, 804, 977, 954], u'name': u'adv'}
    ]
}

print "Ticker name '%s':" % data_dict[u'tickers_data'][0][u'name']

dates = data_dict[u'stats']
amounts = data_dict['tickers_data'][0][u'amount']

for date, amount in zip(dates,amounts):
    print "  Date: %s, Amount: %s" % (date, amount)
```

This gives the following output:

```
Ticker name 'adv':
  Date: Jul 23, 2015, Amount: 936
  Date: Jul 24, 2015, Amount: 804
  Date: Jul 25, 2015, Amount: 977
  Date: Jul 26, 2015, Amount: 954
```

If you wanted to store the data in a file, you could add the following:

```
with open("ticker_data.txt", "w") as f_output:
    f_output.write("Ticker name '%s':\n" % data_dict[u'tickers_data'][0][u'name'])

    for date, amount in zip(dates,amounts):
        f_output.write("  Date: %s, Amount: %s\n" % (date, amount))
```

Tested using Python 2.7